# JavaScript - Create an ad that changes every 3s using a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I need to create an ad that changes pictures automatically after every 3 seconds. This is what I have so far but I am stuck of where to go and how to finish:
1. Declare a variable named currentImage set equal to 1.
2. Declare a variable named autoAdvance and set it to run the ChangeAd()      function every 3 seconds.
3.Create a function named ChangeAd().
4.Within the function, use a case structure to determine the next ad to be displayed.
-Use the currentImage variable in the switch statement.
-For case 1: set the source of the first img element to "concert2.gif" then set the currentImage variable to 2.
-For case 2: set the source of the first img element to "concert3.gif" then set the currentImage variable to 3.
-For case 3: set the source of the first img element to "concert4.gif" then set the currentImage variable to 4.
-For case 4: set the source of the first img element to "concert5.gif" then set the currentImage variable to 5.
-For case 5: set the source of the first img element to "concert1.gif" then set the currentImage variable to 1.
Remember to include break statements where needed.

[edit]

```
 <p><img src="concert1.gif" id="img" height="60" width="370" alt="Changing advertising image" /></p>
 <script>
  "use strict";
  var currentImage = 1;
  var autoAdvance = setInterval(ChangeAd, 3000);

  function ChangeAd(currentImage) {
  var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
     switch(currentImage){
        case 1:
           currentImage = 2;
           return "concert2.gif";
           break;
        case 2:
           curentImage = 3;
           return "concert3.gif";
           break;
        case 3:
           currentImage = 4;
           return "concert4.gif";
           break;
        case 4:
           currentImage = 5;
           return "concert5.gif";
           break;
        case 5:
           currentImage = 1;
           return "concert1.gif";
           break;
     }

  } 
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you [checked your console for errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log#t=201610202230529157306) Yo've got a syntax error right now. Also, pro-tip, don't pass strings to `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Just do `setTimeout(ChangeAd, 3000)`.

Comment: @Alex204 - this sounds like an assignment of sorts. Please be more descriptive about what you want and where you are stuck. As it stands you have some syntax and execution issues but what is this code doing/not doing that you would like changed?

Comment: @CristianCavalli I have added in my requirements, I have them mostly filled just dont know how to end it

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I made an array with all the image paths, and it just cycles over them.
You should probably use something other than `getElementsByTagName` maybe use `getElementById` instead

```
var images = ["concert2.gif", "concert3.gif", "concert4.gif", "concert5.gif", "concert1.gif"];
var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var currentImage = 0;

var autoAdvance = setInterval(ChangeAd, 3000);

function ChangeAd() {
    image.src= images[currentImage];
    currentImage ++;
    if(currentImage == images.length) currentImage = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Alex204 That's a silly requirement. I'll try to work one in there I guess.

Comment: Great answer! You can add this as the first line of the ChangeAd() function to restart the images from the beginning: if(currentImage >= images.length) currentimage = 0;

Comment: To help I have posted my requirements in the comments above

Comment: @Alex204 I'm pretty bored at work, but not bored enough to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Kolby It's not that I dont want to do it but that I dont know how to. I have gotten this far. I am fairly new to JavaScript and am having trouble understanding where to go from here. My teacher isnt helping me in a way that I can understand

Comment: @Kolby As you can see I done most of the steps/requirements, I just dont know how to end it